# What is the internal functioning of the following code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how the following lines of code work in c++.

```
int main(){

    int i;
    i = 1 + (2,3,5,3,6);
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 7
Basically, the answer is the sum of 1 and the last integer in between the parentheses.

Comment: [A good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) should have told you about the [built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Answer (score 0):

(2,3,5,3,6) turns out to be 6.
Hence 1 + 6 = 7

You can verify with a print statement

**`printf("\n%d\n", (2,3,5,3,6));`**

It will print 6 only.